# How to rsync a file which does not have extension?

Tags: rsync, synology

I'm trying to write a script in Synology to copy one system file (a file containing CPU temperature value) to another server. The file does not have extension. I always get the error
rsync: read errors mapping "/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/temp2_input": No data available (61)
Please note that I already created private/public keys for using rsync without having to input the remote server password. I've tried the rsync command in terminal and it produces the same result. The location of the file is definitely correct.
Need your help.

cd /
rsync -e ssh /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/temp2_input bthoven@192.168.x.xx:/usr/share/hassio/homeassistant/syno

rsync: read errors mapping "/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/temp2_input": No data available (61)

Comment: I don't think the extension is the problem. If you read live kernel data like from the /proc file system, these are "dummy" files, i.e., not real, and updated in real time. I'd guess rsync does not deal with that very well. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73569/why-does-rsync-fail-to-copy-files-from-sys-in-linux

Comment: I can use cp command to copy such file to synology home folder and rsync from there. If possible, to rsync direct from source.

Comment: Ok. Rsync can't copy pseudo files; whilst cp can. So I have to copy the file to my Synology home and then rsync to my remote server from there. Thanks.

Comment: I’d recommend trying `scp` instead of `rsync` — it does a relatively plain copy operation (more like `cp` than `rsync`), but remotely over the ssh protocol.